# SRAM Rival chainline on a 1x System, feeling the chain slipping into place

Tags: sram, chainline

I have myself a SRAM Rival ETAP 1x Drivetrain and I am looking for advice here on a problem before I go to a Mechanic.

Is it right to feel the chain slipping into place on the Front Chainring (while pedaling) when staying in the two smallest cassette cogs in the back?

I barely have this feeling while in the easiest gear (largest cassette cog) and I am not sure if the chainline is aligned better toward the centerline of the frame and worse as I shift to the smallest cogs in the rear.

It might be that it's supposed to be like that, but I rather would like to know for sure since it is irritating, and if there is an adjustment or fix for it.

Since the Bike is new and everything is preinstalled I am hesitant to think they made that big an error.   I have tried to find answer to this, and so far it has been very difficult, which is why I am reaching out to this group.

Answer (score 4):

SRAM ETAP is very particular about the setup. There are several how-to videos that SRAM has made to show all the steps. The gap between the upper pulley and the cogs is pretty important.  SRAM should have included a tool to measure it, but you need to do all the steps.

That said, if you did everything by the book and your chain is the correct length, you should not feel any slippage on the front chainring unless the chainline is so bad that it's falling off the chainring to the bottom bracket side.

Are you using SRAM cranks, chainring, and bottom bracket? If you're not this could be the cause of the issue. Also, SRAM will not honour any warranty issues on mixed drivetrains (ask me how I know...).

And there's no shame in taking the bike to the shop if you're stumped. A derailleur adjustment is probably less than $20. (Disclosure: Pro Mechanic)

Comment: Great answer and welcome to the site! Glad to have you here.

Comment: Thank you for responding.

Comment: Its a new Bike with Full Sram Rival set already installed. So i just startet riding it and noticed it on the higher speeds. And the Chain doesnt fall off. Difficult to explain but if i decent and go into the smaller gears i can feel the teeth pushing the chain onto themselves while padeling

Comment: and instead of a smooth quite pedaling experience it feels as too much friction between chain and my 44tooth chainring. I know there would be some but on the easiest gear its barely noticeable